# how do I loop through selected file extensions in ZSH?

Tags: zsh, filenames, brace-expansion

I am looking for a ZSH equivalent to this BASH construct:

```
for file in *.{abc,def,ghi}; do #loop through all files with the extensions .abc, .def and .ghi
```

I cannot find a similar construct for ZSH. Or perhaps there is none?

Comment: The above works for me in zsh; what problem are you encountering?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose that you have the following files: `foo.abc`, `bar.abc`, `qux.ghi`. In bash, the loop body is executed four times: with `foo.abc`, `bar.abc`, `*.def` (with a literal `*`) and `qux.ghi`. In zsh, with default options, the loop is not executed at all, instead you get the error

```
zsh:1: no matches found: *.def
```

To both avoid running the loop on an unexpanded wildcard pattern and do run the loop on the existing files (if any), add the [`N` glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers).

```
for file in *.{abc,def,ghi}(N); do …
```

You can also use the [`|` operator](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Operators), so that you have a single pattern instead of multiple patterns. (Braces aren't a wildcard pattern, they're just a literal string expansion that happens before wildcards are parsed, i.e. `*.{abc,def,ghi}(N)` is just shorthand for `*.abc(N) *.def(N) *.ghi(N)`)

```
for file in *.(abc|def|ghi)(N); do …
```

Note that you still need the `N` glob qualifier, otherwise you'll get an error if no file matches.

Instead of using the `N` glob qualifier, you can [turn on the `null_glob` option](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-NULL_005fGLOB) (`setopt null_glob`). This often makes sense in scripts. Note that in bash, you would need to activate the similar option (`shopt -s nullglob`) to avoid running the loop body on unexpanded patterns.

Comment: A subtle but useful advantage of the`|`operator is that it maintains alphasort ordering by whole filename, rather than by order of the extension in the provided list.